# Constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I need a little help on this View. in practice I would like to reduce the green button in height. I tried to fix it in various ways but either crashes the app or they do not work.

Can anyone tell me how to solve?

Screenshot of the problematic view:

[image: View]

programmatically at this point here. The green part that I have to decrease in height is called "buttonShare"

```
private extension DropPreviewView {

struct Constants {
    static let regionSpan: CLLocationDistance = 250
    static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
    static let headerHeight: CGFloat = 60
}

func setupUI() {

    buttonShare.do {
        $0.backgroundColor = .green
        $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapOutsideView), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    blurredBackgroundView.do {
        $0.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapOutsideView))
        $0.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    spinner.do {
        $0.hidesWhenStopped = true
        $0.color = .darkGray
        $0.startAnimating()
    }

    contentView.do {
        $0.backgroundColor = .white
        $0.clipsToBounds = true
        $0.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
    }

    dropPreviewImageView.do {
        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        $0.clipsToBounds = true
        $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapOnPreviewImage))
        $0.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
}

func arrangeSubviews() {

    addSubview(blurredBackgroundView, constraints: [
        blurredBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        blurredBackgroundView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
        blurredBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        blurredBackgroundView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
        ])

    addSubview(contentView, constraints: [
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
        contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.7),
        contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
        contentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        ])

    addSubview(buttonShare, constraints: [
        buttonShare.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor)
        ])

    header.addConstraint(
        header.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Constants.headerHeight)
    )

    let innerStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [dropPreviewImageView, buttonShare]).then {
        $0.distribution = .fillEqually
        $0.axis = .vertical
        $0.spacing = 10
    }

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [header, innerStack, buttonShare]).then {
        $0.axis = .vertical
        $0.distribution = .fill
        $0.spacing = 10
    }

    contentView.addSubview(stackView, constraints: [
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor),
        ])
    dropPreviewImageView.addSubview(spinner, constraints: [
        spinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dropPreviewImageView.centerXAnchor),
        spinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dropPreviewImageView.centerYAnchor),
        ])
}
```

Comment: Never include code as a picture in your question. Include it as text using proper code formatting.

Comment: @DávidPásztor ok thanks :)

Comment: it seems that you add `buttonShare` as a subview to `self`, then as an arranged subview to `innerStack` and finally as an arranged subview to `stackView`. Do you realize, that a single view can have only one superview? The first two "addings" are nullified by adding it as an arranged subview of the `stackView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
    addSubview(buttonShare, constraints: [
        buttonShare.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor)
        buttonShare.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        buttonShare.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        ])
```

**EDIT:** You'll want to anchor the bottom of the view above the green view to the top of the button. Make sure this is after the code above

Comment: thanks! in this way it is working, now I fix everything. I thank you for the tip :)

Comment: Glad to hear! A mark as answer would be highly appreciated ;)